# SSRS Show line only if data is present

Tags: conditional-statements, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am putting a persons name, their organization, and address block on a report. Sometimes the Applicant_Organization is NULL. When this happens I want to omit that line. With the code I have, an empty line shows below Applicant Name when there is no value for Applicant_Organization value. How can this be worked around?

```
=UCase(First(Fields!Applicant_Name.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & 
 First(Fields!Applicant_Organization.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & 
 First(Fields!Applicant_Address_Block.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: public interface IValidation
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Add error messages.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="key">Name of property.</param>
        /// <param name="errorMessage">Error message</param>
        void AddError(string key, string errorMessage);
        /// <summary>
        /// Return true if no error else false.
        /// </summary>
        bool IsValid { get; }
    }

Comment: public class ModelStateWrapper : IValidation
    {
        private ModelStateDictionary modelState;
  public ModelStateWrapper() : this(new ModelStateDictionary()) { }
     public ModelStateWrapper(ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (modelState == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("modelState");

            this.modelState = modelState;
        }

Comment: public IEnumerable<ErrorData> GetErrorList()
        {
            return GetErrorList(string.Empty);
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use IsNothing() function :

For Example :

```
=UCase(First(Fields!Applicant_Name.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & 
 IIF(IsNothing(First(Fields!Applicant_Organization.Value, "DataSet1")), "", First(Fields!Applicant_Organization.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13)) & 
 First(Fields!Applicant_Address_Block.Value, "DataSet1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. All we do here is test if then organization is blank/null/empty and then just append an empty string, if it is not empty we add the value plus the new line.

```
=UCase(First(Fields!Applicant_Name.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13) & 
 IIF(LEN(First(Fields!Applicant_Organization.Value, "DataSet1")) = 0 , "", First(Fields!Applicant_Organization.Value, "DataSet1") & Chr(10) & Chr(13)) & 
 First(Fields!Applicant_Address_Block.Value, "DataSet1"))
```